# How to convert a string into an integer?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a phone number with a prefix of 050 and add a random 7 digit number to it, and finally return it as an integer, for example: return 0501234567 yet I'm getting the error: "cannot implicitly convert type int to string"

```
        static string generatePhone() {
            Random rand = new Random();
            var number = rand.Next(0, 1000000);
            var phone = "050" + number.ToString("0000000");
            var phoneNumber = (int)Int64.Parse(phone);
            return phoneNumber;
        }
```

Comment: `rand.Next(0, 1000000);` will only give a 6 digit random number.

Comment: A *Phone number* (code) is a string, not an integer. Will you add / multiply or perform other math operations with *phone numbers*, so you need *an integer*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`phoneNumber` is an `int` but your method returns `string`, so either return a `string` not `int` ...

```
static string generatePhone() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    var number = rand.Next(0, 1000000);
    string phone = "050" + number.ToString("0000000");
    return phone;
}
```

... or change the signature of the method. But you lose the leading `0`.

```
static int generatePhone() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    var number = rand.Next(0, 1000000);
    string phone = "050" + number.ToString("0000000");
    int phoneNumber = int.Parse(phone);
    return phoneNumber;
}
```

Comment: But, do note, that the leading `0` will be pointless when converting to an `int`.

Comment: @Luuk: right, mentioned it

Answer (score 0):

```
static int generatePhone() {
```

Change the return type to int instead of string.

Comment: While this is technically a correct answer, I’d recommend looking at the accepted answer, which offers the same advise alongside a lot more detail, thus proving to be far more useful to readers.